# Which code is more effective?

Tags: php, exception

I was wondering which code is more effective, meaning faster & reliable.
When I have my client post data into my website, I don't allow them to use anything else other than Alphanumeric characters because there's no need for others.
My question was, would an exception be faster and more reliable for this? Or should I stay away from exceptions in this purpose?
Here's my code.

Normal Way -

```
function checkStr ($str)
{
  if (preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', $str) > 0))
  {
     return false;
  }
  else
  {
     return true;
  }
}
if (checkStr($_POST['field']) == true)
{
  //continue
}
else
{
  echo "Invalid characters";
}
```

Exception -

```
function checkStr ($str)
{
    if (preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', $str) > 0)
    {
        throw new Exception('Invalid characters');
    }
    return true;
}

    try
    {
        checkStr($_POST['field']);

        //no exception, continue with code 
    }

    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage();

    }
}
```

Comment: my vote gives to later one ( using `Exception` class )

Comment: have you tried benchmarking it?

Comment: i think, after `throw` there is no need to write `return`

Comment: Exceptions are generally slower, not faster.  If you're already returning a boolean, I don't see the point of adding an exception to indicate failure when you're already doing so with the boolean.

Comment: It would depend on how you want to handle the errors. If you are using exceptions handlers, then use the 2nd method. If you just want to display an error message then use 1st one. You can simulate the 1st one through 2nd method, but not vice-versa. Exceptions will be slower as compared to the 1st method.

Answer (score 2):

Although Exceptions will have some performance overhead, performance is not the only criterion. Consider also code size and complexity, and overall maintainability.

Very often I encounter code where return values from methods are not checked and hence errors are ignored.

Which code is easier to understand

```
 if ( do this ) 
     if (do that)
        if (something else)
            OK
        else
            bad something
      else
         bad that
 else
      bad this
```

or with exceptions

```
 try
     do this
     do that
     something else
 catch
     report error
```

I'm not a php programmer, but in Java I tend to use exceptions quite a lot.

Comment: Having spent countless hours on maintaining unmaintainable legacy code, I strongly vote for the version with exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions have more overhead associated with them than normal program flow control features (if, else, elseif, etc), so purely from that point of view the first option is faster.  Exceptions are tricky things, and because they're a relatively new addition to PHP people tend to overuse them.  Normally, I try to only throw exceptions when the circumstances that have occured in the code are exceptional.

For example, if I have a function where the valid inputs are the integers 1-100, then I'd have it return true for an input of 40, false for an input of 493, and throw an exception for an input of "kumquat".

BTW, you can write the first version of your function in a single line:

```
function checkStr ($str)
{
    return (preg_match('/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/', $str) > 0));
}
```